# VBA Compile Error - Show Userform

Tags: vba, excel

In my Workbook (Book1) i have a Command Button which opens a new Workbook, import two Userforms to the new Workbook and creats two Command Buttons.

But if i want to click on one of these Command Buttons, the Error Msg "Compile Error: Object libary invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found."

If i creat manually a new workbook, import the UFs with drag & drop and create the Buttons everything works fine.

Here are my macros:

```
' Book1 CommandButton

Private Sub PM_Controlling_Click()
    Dim relativePath As String
    Dim btn1 As Object
    Dim Code As String

' Create new Book:
    Workbooks.Add
    relativeString = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Book2"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativeString & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

' Import UserForm:
    Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents.Import Filename:="C:\Users\UserForm\Add\UserForm1.frm"
    Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents.Import Filename:="C:\Users\UserForm\Add\UserForm2.frm"

' Create Button for UserForm1:
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=110, Height:=25)
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1).Object.Caption = "Project Report"
    btn.Name = "Project_Report"

' Code for UserForm1:
    Code = "Private Sub Project_Report_Click()" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "    [UserForm1].Show" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "End Sub"

    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).CodeName).CodeModule
        .insertlines .CountOfLines + 1, Code
    End With

' Create Button for UserForm2:
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=10, Top:=40, Width:=110, Height:=25)
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(2).Object.Caption = "Watch Project Report"
    btn.Name = "Watch_Report"

' Code for UserForm2:
    Code = "Private Sub Watch_Report_Click()" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "    [UserForm2].Show" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "End Sub"

    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).CodeName).CodeModule
        .insertlines .CountOfLines + 1, Code
    End With
End Sub


 ' Code in Book2
Private Sub Project_Report_Click()
    [UserForm1].Show
End Sub

Private Sub Watch_Report_Click()
    [UserForm2].Show
End Sub

' UserForm1 Code
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   UserForm2.Label1 = TextBox1.Value
   UserForm2.Label2 = TextBox2.Value
   UserForm2.Label3 = TextBox3.Value
   UserForm2.Label4 = TextBox4.Value

   [UserForm1].Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
   [UserForm1].Hide
End Sub

'UserForm2 Code
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   [UserForm2].Hide
End Sub
```

The Part in Book2 **[UserForm1].Show** is highlighted blue and causes the error.

Hope someone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: After importing check whether `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library` added to VBA reference. else add programmatically `ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\System32\FM20.DLL"`

Comment: The Userforms are added, at least they are displayed in the VBA reference

Comment: @nagarajannd even if i change the part `[UserForm1].Show` to for example to `MsgBox "Test"` the error appears.